# Filter grouped_collection_select by owner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using a `grouped_collection_select` to set up polymorphic associations within my rails app.  I'm using it to establish an association between a `Stockholder` and the models`Org` and `Person`.  All three belong to a `Company`.

Or, to put it more verbosely, `Stockholder`

```
has_many :people,    through: :entity_joins
has_many :orgs, through: :entity_joins
```

and `Company`

```
has_many :people
has_many :orgs
```

Currently the `grouped_collection_select` is set up as follows:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :global_entity, [Org, Person], :all, :model_name, :to_global_id, :name %>
```

The issue is that the above code provides a list of ALL `orgs` and `people`, not just those belonging to the `Company` at hand.  I imagine that the `:all` option is the cause of this but I can't figure out how to only list `orgs` and `people` that belong to a particular `company`.

So my question is: How do I filter options so that only those belonging to the right `Company` (`@company`) are available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know, what form is that, but you should lean on company.

If it is form for company, you can get the company through `f.object` (which should be the `company`)

I think

```
[f.object.orgs, f.object.persons]
```

instead of

```
[Org, Person]
```

will work :)